# Problems tagging the message author in node js

Tags: node.js, discord, tagging

Trying to make a command that when used will tag the user who used the command, tag a role and add two reactions. The role tag and the reactions work but I cannot get the person who used the command to be tagged. Any ideas if its a simply syntax error or the `message.author` format is wrong for this application, thank you.

```
    client.on('message', message => {
    if (message.content === '!rankup')
        message.channel.send(' ${message.author} <@&869746450794418186>, is looking for rankup').then(sentMessage => {
            sentMessage.react('☑️');
            sentMessage.react('✅');
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use backticks, i.e

```
   //(`${variable} other strings`)


   `${message.author} <@&869746450794418186>, is looking for rankup`
```

instead of double quotes("") or single quotes('')